# Speed discrepancies when selecting different records in same table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I've got a pretty basic SQL query that's become a bottleneck in my processing.  It's selecting a large varchar(999) column that's slowing it down. Removing that column from the select speeds it up considerably so I know it's the column that's causing problem.

I was experimenting with breaking it up into smaller 300 record batches to see if that helped and I saw something weird happening. Some of the batches were taking almost 30 seconds, and some were taking 0.012 seconds. I don't know what's causing this discrepancy.

I have a reproducible scenario where the first query is taking many times faster than the 2nd:

```
select r.ID, r.FileID, r.Data
from Calls c 
join RawData r on r.ID = c.ID 
join DataFiles f on f.ID = r.FileID 
where r.ID between 1118482415 and 1118509835
```

0.3 seconds

```
select r.ID, r.FileID, r.Data
from Calls c 
join RawData r on r.ID = c.ID 
join DataFiles f on f.ID = r.FileID 
where r.ID between 1115330220 and 1118482415
```

8 seconds

I see no visible differences in the returned data. They both return 300 records and all of the record's "Data" column values are about 170 characters long.  I'm running this directly from the SqlStudio client. Also there's no other traffic in this database.

Does anybody know what could be causing this problem or have any suggestions to try? I can't decrease the size of the column because there are some bigger records in there, just not in this example. I do have indexes on all the columns used in the joins (Calls.ID, RawData.ID, RawData.FileID, DataFiles.ID).

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` and explore query plan

Comment: T-SQL doesn't have EXPLAIN but I did look at their execution plans.  They are different. The slower one is doing an index scan on an index on DataFiles that includes ID and its LoadDate column that's not contained in my query.  Not sure why it'd be doing that.

Comment: Different estimated row counts.

Comment: Look at query plans.  And you may have a row with corrupt data.  I know sounds strange but do a top and see is it tanks out a certain row.  As strange as it sounds it has happened to me.  Run a CHECKTABLE on the table and defragment all the indexes.